# using filtering json and getting TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I was trying to convert .csv file to json and need to filter some fields in Json and getting the error

```
like tranId = 1;

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from collections import defaultdict
df = pd.read_csv('E:/Transactional_data/transaction.csv')
#print(df);

index = df.index
columns = df.columns
values = df.values

#print(index)
#print(columns)
#print(values)

df.columns = df.columns.str.strip();
#print(df.columns);
jsondf = df.to_json( orient='index')
#print(jsondf);
todos = json.loads(json.dumps(jsondf))
print(todos)

CL_NOME = type(todos['tranId'])


{  
   "0":{  
      "tranId":1,
      "prodId":10,
      "tranAmt":1000.0,
      "tranDt":" 2018-10-01 10:10:10"
   },
   "1":{  
      "tranId":2,
      "prodId":10,
      "tranAmt":1000.0,
      "tranDt":" 2018-10-01 10:15:10"
   },
   "2":{  
      "tranId":3,
      "prodId":20,
      "tranAmt":2000.0,
      "tranDt":" 2018-10-01 10:15:20"
   },
   "3":{  
      "tranId":4,
      "prodId":10,
      "tranAmt":1000.0,
      "tranDt":" 2018-10-01 10:10:10"
   },
   "4":{  
      "tranId":5,
      "prodId":30,
      "tranAmt":3000.0,
      "tranDt":" 2018-10-01 10:20:10"
   },
   "5":{  
      "tranId":6,
      "prodId":20,
      "tranAmt":2000.0,
      "tranDt":" 2018-10-01 10:15:30"
   }
}
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to get output for todos['tranId'] == 1 , but getting type error.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why the `json.loads(json.dumps(jsondf))`? If you remove the `json.dumps()` (just using loads) then you can access your "orient='index'" json with something like - `print(f'todos zero tranid is {todos["0"]["tranId"]}')` to get the value of 1. Is that what you are after?

Comment: please put more effort to edit your question/ explain what you want to accomplish with the current code that you exposed in the question

Answer (score 0):

your `todos` is a string (seems like you are expecting to be a dict), you should use:

```
todos = json.loads(jsondf)
```

even so, you will get a KeyError, if you want to take the type of `tranId` field you should use:

```
type(todos['0']['tranId'])  # which will be <class 'int'>
```

if you want to take the row for which `tranId` is equal with 1 you can use:

```
tranId_1_output = next(filter(lambda x: x['tranId'] == 1, todos.values()))
print(tranId_1_output)

# output: {'tranId': 1, 'tranDt': ' 2018-10-01 10:10:10', 'tranAmt': 1000.0, 'prodId': 10}
```